# How to use a specific self-signed certificate with IIS Express (rather than the default localhost)

Tags: visual-studio, iis, ssl, ssl-certificate, iis-express

I am having trouble finding a specific example for how I specify a self-signed certificate for IIS Express - Visual Studio 2015 - rather than the default generated 'localhost' certificate.

I'd like to use one from my personal self-signed certificates store to correspond with a specific domain I am using during development.

I cannot locate where to specify the certificate (or its footprint).

Comment: Jexus Manager for IIS can guide you by creating a self signed certificate with desired common name in server level Certificates and also managing site bindings with proper certificate selected. Try it out, https://jexus.codeplex.com/releases/view/138373 Make sure you add the solution level applicationHost.config file as a new server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use makecert to do that, long time ago I wrote a document on how to do that and you can find the blog here:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

the key call is:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=HANSELMAN-W500" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2036 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localMachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12
```

where you can choose the CNAME that you want there.